# Add-in developed for Outlook 2010 on Win7. How can I make it available on all Office application like Word or PPT?

Tags: plugins, vsto, add-in, outlook-addin, office-addins

The add-in we have developed works well on Outlook 2010. Can we reconfigure the same exe so that it gets installed on all Office apps like Word, Xls, PPT etc., including Outlook in one shot?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [**separate installer** for each Office product](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) (*Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Publisher, OneNote, Project, etc.*) you want to use your add-in for. If you have shared behavior for the add-in amongst Office products, you can factor it out into its own assembly (*i.e. Class Library*) and have it shared between all projects.

**Visual Studio** has [separate project templates for each Office product](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8553caee%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#AppLevel) you intend to create Office add-ins for. You can follow the same pattern for integration with VSTO as you did with Outlook to integrate with other products - they just [require their own project/assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386298.aspx) since each product is an entirely different application boundary and requires its own [deployment manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb771323.aspx).